# Login session not persist in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I have ungraded my laravel project from 5.1 to 6. I upgraded the project like this->

- first I created fresh laravel 6 project.
- then i copy paste my codes from my old version to new version.

While doing so i'm facing this problem. I used separate controller and route for authenticating a user. while authenticating the user the login session is not persist, so it is redirecting me back to login page again. I've checked that my credential for login is correct and `Auth::attempt` also return true. But when i redirecting it to my desire route, that where it sent me to login page.

```
public function signInAction(Request $request)
    if (Auth::attempt($loginCredentials)) {
        $logonId = $secUserLogon[0]->logon_id;
        $request->session()->put('sessLogonId', $logonId); // this session data in not available later on

        return redirect()->intended(route('home::onlineInfo'));
    }
}
```

I found a workaround, which seems not right. I have passed true as 2nd parameter in `Auth::attempt` which is letting me logged in the user. But if i put anything in session, its not persist either, and if i implement remember me, it will not work if user pass false. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Why have you created your own authentication rather than just using the one Laravel provides and has been tested?

Comment: @MartinBean its an old project to the company that i worked in, and there is few other condition that we need to apply before authenticating a user

Comment: Laravel’s `AuthenticatesUsers` trait has hooks that allow you to modify the login process, i.e. adding additional validation before authenticating a user: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L57-L71

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the global `session()` helper? This may be more reliable. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#storing-data

Comment: thats not the case, I haven't give the code here. Due to it will make the question bigger.. as i told in the question, Auth::attempt condition return true. it is letting me through in if condition block..

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying and sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated my answer to remove that bit.

Comment: I've tried that too... But it's not working either.. What i'm guessing it's middleware issue.. But couldn't figured it out